# How do I access a network printer from a windows printing server?

Tags: linux-mint, printing

I only have the windows server address which is `192.168.100.12` and the printer's model which is `HP LaserJet P1606`.

I can print on that printer from windows machine but how can I do from Linux? The printer has an IP that is not on the same network; that's why I need to access it from the windows printing server which is on same network.

My OS is `Linux Mint 17`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the LPD service to the printing role on windows server.

On linux, open your system configuration tool then add a network printer, choose the `LPD/LPR Host or printer` and then type the name or ip address of your windows printing server and the printer share name like this : `lpd://192.168.100.12/IT_SUPPORT`.

The `share name` can be found in the properties of the printer.

[image]

I don't know why but it doesn't work with names containing spaces so you better replace them with underscores.